# Rails way to convert match feature value to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a piece of routes.rb code from my first project:

```
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
```

I can use 'signup_path' and 'signin_path' using this routes.rb. And there is the following routes.rb code from my second project:

```
  resources :places, only: [:index]
  match '/places/by_type/:id', to: 'places#filter'
```

I hoped to be able to use 'places_by_type_path', but I was wrong. Please, tell me, why were paths automatically built in the first case? Why must I use 'as' construction for the second case? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found [this on Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/231-routing-walkthrough?view=asciicast). It will automatically fill in your :as parameter as long as your path does not have any non-word characters (':' for example).

```
def normalize_options!
    path_without_format = @path.sub(/\(\.:format\)$/, '')

    if using_match_shorthand?(path_without_format, @options)
      to_shorthand    = @options[:to].blank?
      @options[:to] ||= path_without_format[1..-1].sub(%r{/([^/]*)$}, '#\1')
      @options[:as] ||= Mapper.normalize_name(path_without_format)
    end

    @options.merge!(default_controller_and_action(to_shorthand))
  end
# match "account/overview"
def using_match_shorthand?(path, options)
  path && options.except(:via, :anchor, :to, :as).empty? && path =~ %r{^/[\w\/]+$}
end
```

This is what you need to do with the :as parameter:

```
match '/places/by_type/:id', to: 'places#filter', as: 'places_by_type'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

Comment: I know it. I don't understand why paths were created automatically without using "as" in the first case

Comment: the difference appears when params come in the game

Answer (score 0):

Your routes are wrong, stick to REST principles to keep a clean app:

```
resources :places, only: [:index] do
  member do
    get :by_type, action: :filter #, as: 'a_name' if needed
  end
end
```

This way you'll have `/places/:id/by_type`

Use `rake routes` to check the named route, use `as` option if needed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it seems to be the :id parameter. Try this:

```
match '/places/by_type/', to: 'places#filter'
```

And to pass a parameter:

```
places_by_type_path(id: my_id)
```